# support for Multiple support resolution after created all layout xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create different layouts for each different resolution of android smartphone. So I created all layouts, listed here:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml
```

But do I have to specify "use that layout"? Because in small screen resolution like Nexus S, when I create the final apk, the layout is the same as the others.

Comment: are you sure that's what you want to do? in 99% of cases you don't need a different layout per screen-size, you just use `dp` for sizes, `wrap_content`/`match_parent` for `width`/`height` behaviors, and alignment to left/center/right for everything else. we have a pretty big project, with lots of layouts, and not once did we need to create a different layout per screen size.

Comment: Hi marmor, so do you advise me to create different "values" files and for each ones, create for example a "size" propert? I made it, but also in this case the layout don't change and textsize it's too big.. How did you do?

Answer (score 0):

The current best way to create different layouts for different screen sizes is to use the *smallest width* qualifier.

The Nexus S has a width of 320dp. More modern phones have larger widths: the Nexus 5 has a width of 360dp and the Pixel has a width a little larger than 400dp. Seven-inch tablets generally have a width of at least 600dp, and ten-inch tablets generally have a width of at least 720dp.

Considering all that, you could make this directory structure:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml
res/layout-sw360dp/my_layout.xml
res/layout-sw400dp/my_layout.xml
res/layout-sw600dp/my_layout.xml
res/layout-sw720dp/my_layout.xml
```

The last layout (the `sw720dp` one) will be used on any device that is 720dp wide or larger. The `sw600dp` layout will be used on any device that is 600dp - 719dp wide. The `sw400dp` layout will be used on any device that is 400dp - 599dp wide. And so on.

Comment: Hi Ben, so I need to change the layout file name ore create these other files?